# HttpClient high data usage when getting remote file size

Tags: c#

I'm getting the file size of remote urls and I just noticed the difference between HttpClient and httpWebRequest.

I compared and I noticed that httpclient is taking too much data.
this is a big issue for me because, in the Philippines we are only have limited data

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my httpclient class? I can't figure out what is causing the high data usage

HttpClient

```
       HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = null,
            UseProxy = false,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "GET");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", uriPath.AbsoluteUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.samplesite.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriPath, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var resultTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(3000);

            var completed = await Task.WhenAny(resultTask, timeoutTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (completed == timeoutTask)
                return null;

            return await resultTask;
        }
```

HttpWebRequest

```
      var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriPath);
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36";

        using (var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), token);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350338/34092 ?

Comment: Alright let me see thank you

Comment: You are using different HTTP methods GET in case of HttpClient & HEAD in case of WebRequest. To get file size you will enough HEAD method in both cases.

Comment: @DmitryKolchev I have tried. but it takes about 15minutes to read the file size
you can see here what I did. I believe I'm still doing wrong https://i.imgur.com/nmTqlj5.jpg

Comment: @zackmark15 you must use SendAsync method instead of GetAsync. GetAsync method always use GET method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different HTTP methods GET in case of HttpClient & HEAD in case of WebRequest. To get file size you will enough HEAD method in both cases

> The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

> The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that are returned if the specified resource would be requested with an HTTP GET method. Such a request can be done before deciding to download a large resource to save bandwidth, for example.

You need to change this code line

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "GET");
```

it MUST BE

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "HEAD");
```

A response to a HEAD method does not have a body in contradistinction to GET

UPD: use SendAsync method (not GetAsync)

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
using var client = new HttpClient(handler);

string requestUri = "enter request uri";

HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, requestUri);
using var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
```

Comment: Thank you for this information I didn't know. 
I already changed it to HEAD but my problem now is taking about 15minutes to finish reading the content length here's my update code 
https://i.imgur.com/nmTqlj5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's solved Big thanks to @Dmitry

Here's the HttpClient updated code

```
   public static async Task<string> GetTotalBytes(Uri uriPath)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Proxy = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uriPath);
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(message))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var lenght = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                return lenght.ToString();
            }
        }
     }
```

RESULT (HttpClient):

```
Total URL: 355
Filsize: 1.14 GB
Elapsed Time: 0h 0m 2s 51.3ms
```

and here's HttpWebRequest (Maybe someone will need)

```
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriPath);
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        webRequest.Proxy = null;

        using (var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), token);
        }
```